# findOrCreate in Loopback model

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, loopbackjs, strongloop

I found an interesting problem on loopback. I was confused when I was adding records with `findOrCreate`. Let's see the example:

```
  for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    console.log(x);
    var Log = app.models.Log;
    Log.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        modelName: '123'
      }
    }, {
      modelName: '123'
    }, function(err, log) {
      if (err) return;
      if (log) {
        console.log("+ " + log.id);
      }
    });
  }
```

I think it should create 1 record with `modelName` '123' only, but I got 10 finally.

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected. You are running the code synchronously. If you run it in an asynchronous way, you will see only one document being created. Try this:

```
var arr = new Array(10);
async.eachSeries(arr, function (pos, callback) {
    console.log(pos);
    Log.findOrCreate({
      where: {
        txt: '123'
      }
    }, {
      txt: '123'
    }, function (err, log) {
      if (err) return;
      console.log("+ " + log.id);
      callback();
    });
  }, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: You are a star! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Are you sure that .findOrCreate() takes where key inside filter object ? 
If i use
`.findOrCreate({where: {key: 'value'}})`
then created object does not contain specified value, it's null instead.
But if i use
`.findOrCreate({key: 'value'})`
everything seems to be correct.
Tough item in database is stored correctly in both cases.

Comment: @Kpihus Please look at this post for a detailed discussion on this issue: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/issues/766